# IIS Windows Authentication + ASP.NET Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, iis, authorization

Building an ASP.NET intranet web application in VB.NET that (hypothetically) relies on Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation to permit domain users to perform certain actions on the server such as reading/writing from shared folder access (all machines on same network/domain). I'm having trouble writing to a share that my domain-user has access to under the expected scenario.

If IIS is set to use `Basic Authentication` + `ASP.NET Impersonation` and I provide my domain login info, then this:

```
Dim FilePath As String = "\\SomeServerName\ShareIHaveAccessTo\FileName.bin"
Dim SomeData As String = "TESTING123"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(FilePath, SomeData, False)
```

...works just fine, and writes the file to the shared folder. But using `Basic Authentication` means I have to manually type my username and password into a browser-auth-prompt every time I access the site.

But If I use `Windows Authentication` + `ASP.NET Impersonation` and attempt the run the same code, I don't have to manually provide my credentials anymore, BUT, the write operation **fails** telling me:

```
' Access to the path '\\SomeServerName\ShareIHaveAccessTo\FileName.bin' is denied.

' at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)`
' at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
' at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
' at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
' at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
' at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
' at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.WriteAllText(String file, String text, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
' at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.WriteAllText(String file, String text, Boolean append)
' at Web_Board_Agenda_Manager__WBAM_._default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\-DevelopmentPathRemoved-\default.aspx.vb:line 25
```

Why would this work *perfectly* with `Basic Auth` but not with `Windows Auth`? I have `Anonymous Auth` disabled, so if `Windows Auth` *itself* was failing, the site wouldn't load at all. How is it that I can successfully authenticate and impersonate, but only using `Basic Auth` will allow me to do the file-write operations on my profile's shared folders?

P.S.,

- I also printed out `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, and `Environment.UserName` on page load. They **don't** change between Basic and Windows Auth.
- I also tried manually impersonating in-code, same result.
- I even tried directly forcing the AppPool in IIS to use my domain username/password. Still no dice using Win Auth.

Comment: When credentials are required in double-hop scenarios like yours, only Basic authentication and Kerberos authentication might work. The error you met simply indicates the domain administrators didn't configure Kerberos to work properly and only they know how to resolve that. In the long run, try to find SSO based end-to-end solutions to replace such.

Comment: I know we have other applications that use ASP.NET `Windows Authentication` for database access, don't know about fileshare access though. Sounds like I've gotten myself in over my head.

Comment: What's the user at the time when got denied message? And did you add app pool or domain user into folder security properties to allow it control folder?

Comment: @Bruce Zhang - All instances of current-, environment-, principal-, and context- user show my domain/useraccount as being the 'working' account. I am clearly authenticated because I can see the site. I am Impersonated because the items change when I turn it off, and when it's on, they reflect my account, same as using Basic. I know my account has access to the share because it's the SAME account used in basic auth, which successfully writes the data to the folder. But using the Windows Auth method, I can't even SEE the shared folder... even though I can see the page.

Comment: To be clear, Windows Authentication is working *for the site itself.* I can also write data to folders *on that same server* that are locked down to only my domain user account.

The issue I am having is *accessing profile-mapped shares on other (local) servers,* which for some reason works using basic auth, but, unintuitively, not windows auth.

Comment: Have you tried windows authentication and imperosnation in visual studio? Did it can work or report any error?

Comment: @BruceZhang - I don't know how to impersonate the IIS-WinAuth'd user in VS without requiring a manually-provided password, which sort of defeats the point. Not saying there isn't a way, but I wasn't able to come up with it.

(On another note, I went ahead and had our enterprise team create a new AD account with read-only permissions to the share, which my web app manually impersonates in-code using stored, encrypted credentials. Solves the problem, but my question is still unanswered...)